# trying to setup variables using from predefined variables from bash script in Azure pipelines

Tags: shell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to setup variables from predefined variables through bash script using bash script. but could not get succedeed. below is my task in azure pipeline

```
  resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline1
  project: appcom
  source: pipeline-api
  trigger:
  branches:
  - develop
  - feat/*
  - pipeline: pipeline2
  project: appcom
  source: pipeline2-api
  trigger:
  branches:
  - develop
  - feat/*
  variables:
 - name: alias
   value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)

 stages:
 - stage: ScanImage

     jobs:
     - job: ScanImage
       pool:
         vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'

       steps:
       - script: echo $(alias)

       - task: Bash@3
         inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
         if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)")
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline1-api")
         elif [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline2" ]; then
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.pipelineName)")
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7")
           echo ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline2")
           fi
       - script: echo $(dockertag)
       - script: echo $(helmpath)
       - script: echo $(apiname)
```

it giving me error with ##[error]Bash exited with code '2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Set variables in scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts), below yaml should work as expected.

```
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeline1
    project: appcom
    source: pipeline-api
    trigger:
      branches:
      - develop
      - feat/*
  - pipeline: pipeline2
    project: appcom
    source: pipeline2-api
    trigger:
      branches:
      - develop
      - feat/*
    
variables:
- name: alias
  value: $(resources.triggeringAlias)

stages:
- stage: ScanImage
  jobs:
  - job: ScanImage
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
    steps:
    - script: echo $(alias)

    - task: Bash@3
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          if [ "$(alias)" == "pipeline1" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.pipelineName)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline1.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline1-api"
          elif [ "$(alias)" = "pipeline2" ]; then
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=apiname]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.pipelineName)"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=dockertag]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceCommit) | cut -c -7"
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=helmpath]P02565Mallorca/pipeline2-api"
          fi

    - script: echo $(dockertag)
    - script: echo $(helmpath)
    - script: echo $(apiname)
```

See:[Resources: pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#resources-pipelines) for more details.

Comment: It is my pleasure to help you.

Comment: Hi Edward, i followed as you mentioned and setting up branchName as variable as below
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=branchName]$(resources.pipeline.pipeline2.sourceBranch)"
but i could not use this variable in condition for as stage 
stages:
- stage: DEV_DCR
condition: and(succeeded(), or(eq(variables $(branchName), 'refs/heads/develop'), eq(variables$(branchName), 'refs/heads/release'), contains(variables$(branchName), 'refs/heads/hotfix/'), contains(variables$(branchName), 'refs/heads/bugfix/')))..... it gives error. any idea how  we can use it

Comment: You should use ```stageDependencies.stageName.jobName.outputs['stepName.variableName']``` not ```variables$(branchName)``` in condition, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#jobs-can-access-output-variables-from-previous-stages and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-stage for details. BTW, please file a new ticket if you have more questions with detailed information. Thanks.

Comment: is it possible to tag above pipeline with $(alias), so i can have filter to list release for each api ??

Comment: or is it possible to name pipeline with something like this 
name: $(alias)